# Flutter - 3rd party JAR code will run from within Android Studio but not from VS Code

Tags: flutter

I'm using VS Code to develop a test flutter app that uses Symbol/Zebra's EMDK to interact with a barcode scanner.  This involves some custom code on the Android side, which has been implemented, and if I open the Android code within Android Studio and run it on my device everything works fine, but if I then go back to my VS Code and try to run the flutter project I get an error "Unfortunately app has stopped".  I suspect this is more of an issue around the 3rd part JAR file not being included when run from the VS code side, but I'm not familiar enough with where I need to include it (Gradle, IML files) in order to make it work.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a libs folder, for example, which should be at `android/libs` and place your jar file there. Then add the following to your `android/build.gradle` file at the bottom:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
}
```